# Error Validation using 'while not in'

Tags: python

I am trying to modify a program that plays the game 'Rock, Paper, Scissors', so that it observes data validation. This objective here is that the validation is done so by ensuring that the user input is equal to 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors', before `userMove` will `return`

Below is a function, I created for the user's input where I have used a `while not in` to validate the user's input and either `return` a valid input or `print` a string, asking for a valid input.

Question: is this the most effective way to validate in **this** instance? Perhaps using the `ValueError` function is more effective?

```
def userMove():
    usersMove = input("Time to make your choice: ")
    while usersMove not in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']:
        print("That is not a valid")
        usersMove = input("Time to make your choice: ")
    return usersMove
```

Comment: try to use `usersMove.lower()` in the while condition. So that, even if user enters `ROCK`, it will work

Comment: What do you mean by "effective"? Compared to what?

Comment: Why has your game one rock, one sheet of paper but many scissors? Isn't that unfair?

Comment: @Paebbels That's not "unfair", that's *English*. And it's not "many" but a *pair*.

Comment: @Paebels - haha It's an example of 'plurale tantum'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you could do is use a set since lookups are faster in sets than in list, also as a comment said, using [`.lower()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lower.htm) would make your code more robust:

```
def userMove():
    usersMove = input("Time to make your choice: ")
    while usersMove.lower() not in {'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'}:
        print("That is not a valid")
        usersMove = input("Time to make your choice: ")
    return usersMove
```

**EDIT**

Also, as @utengr pointed out, using my previous recommendations you could transform your code like this also,

```
def userMove():
    while True:
        usersMove = input("Time to make your choice: ")
        if usersMove.lower() in {'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'}:
            return usersMove
        print("That is not a valid")
```

Note that your question was about performance. Using the second solution will not affect performance in any way, the main gain here is regarding readability since you compact the code into one block.

Comment: For a list of length 3, there's practically no difference in lookup time. But with a larger N, set lookup is much faster  O(1) vs O(n)

Comment: I know, he will never be able to see the difference in this example, but his question was: _is this the most effective way to validate in this instance?_ So I thought giving him an alternative would make him see this possibility.

Comment: Great to know, for future Python endeavors, for larger N.

Answer (score 3):

You should use sets for membership checks as they are faster than lists. Moreover, `while true` is preferred over a `while some condition`[[Python docs]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop).

```
def userMove():
    while True:
        usersMove = input("Time to make your choice: ")
        if usersMove in {'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'}:
            return usersMove
        print("That is not a valid")
```

You can also add `usersMove.lower()` to it if you don't want case sensitivity as suggested by @scharette and @yklsga.

Comment: maybe a comment on my post would have been better. It is practically the same exact answer as mine with one line changed. It is ok though I'm just saying. nice insight!

Comment: @scharette Nah, this is much better than yours. The difference is significant.

Comment: @utengr you did not treated my answer. I really did not mean it that way. I was just saying we had two really similar answers. But people seem not to agree, so it is perfectly fine that way. As I said, good insight ! I will add an edit my self

Comment: I appreciate all opinions aired - the insight you've all given is fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in `set.__contains__` and `list.__contains__` is a few nanoseconds at best. But the difference in user input speed in measured in milliseconds or more! So the most effective is to let the user input just a single letter.

```
def fast_user_move():
    while True:
        usersMove = input("Time to make your choice: ").lower().strip()
        if usersMove and usersMove[0] in 'rps':
            return usersMove[0]
        print("That is not a valid choice")
```

For a super effective solution, use the [readchar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readchar) library, and the user only have to push a single button **return key not needed!**

```
from readchar import readchar

def super_fast_user_move():
    print('Time to make your choice: [r]ock, [p]aper or [s]cissors?')
    while True:
        choice = readchar().lower()
        if choice in 'rps':
            return choice
        print(f'{choice} is not a valid choice')
```

**Edit**: This blazing speed comes at a cost! If the user tries to enter *STOP*, the input will be interpreted as *Scissors* instead, which could lead to all sorts of danger. Thanks to @scharette for the warning.

**Edit 2**: Here's some benchmarks I did. As you can see, this version is almost 200 times faster than the original, measured in wall time.

```
In [12]: %time userMove()
Time to make your choice: scissor
That is not a valid
Time to make your choice: scissors
CPU times: user 1e+03 µs, sys: 1 ms, total: 2 ms
Wall time: 6.02 s
Out[12]: 'scissors'


In [13]: %time super_fast_user_move()
Time to make your choice: [r]ock, [p]aper or [s]cissors?
CPU times: user 1 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 1 ms
Wall time: 34.6 ms
Out[13]: 's'
```

(But it should be noted I did misspell "scissors" once.)

Comment: Be really careful using this, comparing against the first letter is rarely a good idea since someone could enter _stop_ as a value and your program would consider the input as scissors.

Comment: Thanks Håken - noted on this very useful point for a rookie, like me!

Comment: In terms of UI/UX, I like this solution best, especially if the prompt was something like 'r(ock), p(paper), or s(cissors)? '

Comment: @scharette Thanks for that warning. I've updated my answer to include your input.